# c# acces array outside for loop

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, split

i was wondering how to acces a array outside a forloop.

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Customers/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");



         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
             string[] linesSplitted = lines[i].Split(':');

         }

         TextboxName.Text = linesSplitted[0];
         TextboxAddress.Text = linesSplitted[1];
         TextboxZip.Text = linesSplitted[2];
         TextboxTel.Text = linesSplitted[3];
         TextboxEmail.Text = linesSplitted[4];
```

at this point, it does not recognize linesSplitted.

Comment: declare the array outside the loop...

Comment: or move the code that accesses the array into the loop, there's 4 arrays being created here, which one to use?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i am not sure what you mean, this is all the code that is needed, i dont have any more code for this subject

Comment: Never mind my original comment, it was wrong, go with what @MitchWheat says instead.

Comment: @MitchWheat When i do that, i get an error saying: "Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'linesSplitted'"

Comment: You are creating 4 arrays. Which one do you want to access?

Comment: You're overriding linesSplitted 4 times. Only the last call will have a effect.

Comment: @Serge How do i solve this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment on another answer, I guess you want this:

```
string[] linesSplitted = new string[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    linesSplitted[i] = lines[i].Split(':')[1];
}
```

If this is not what you want, give us an example of the contents of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array outside of the loop. E.g.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Customers/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");

string[] linesSplitted;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   linesSplitted = lines[i].Split(':');
}

TextboxName.Text = linesSplitted[0];
TextboxAddress.Text = linesSplitted[1];
TextboxZip.Text = linesSplitted[2];
TextboxTel.Text = linesSplitted[3];
TextboxEmail.Text = linesSplitted[4];
```

Comment: The `for` loop is equivalent to `linesSplitted = lines[3].Split(':');`

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Customers/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");


     string[] linesSplitted;
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
         linesSplitted = lines[i].Split(':');

     }

     TextboxName.Text = linesSplitted[0];
     TextboxAddress.Text = linesSplitted[1];
     TextboxZip.Text = linesSplitted[2];
     TextboxTel.Text = linesSplitted[3];
     TextboxEmail.Text = linesSplitted[4];
```

I'm not to sure about what you're trying to achieve there...

Comment: I have a textfile containing some information. i want this displayed in the textbox. but only what comes after ":" example: "name: serge" i onle want the textbox to be filled with "serge"

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Customers/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");


 List<string[]> data  = new List<string[]>(); 
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
            data.Add(lines[i].Split(':'));
         }

//Retrive array from list and value from array and set to text box

         TextboxName.Text = linesSplitted[0];
         TextboxAddress.Text = linesSplitted[1];
         TextboxZip.Text = linesSplitted[2];
         TextboxTel.Text = linesSplitted[3];
         TextboxEmail.Text = linesSplitted[4];
```

Comment: i get an error saying: "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'"

Comment: It works for me dude..Please retrive value correctly..I think issue is in retrieving values.